# Cannot set start value of sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, sequence, flyway

I am using migration script in my Spring Boot app and create a sequence as shown below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS public.sequence_user START WITH 4 INCREMENT BY 5;
```

Then, in another migration file, I insert 3 users via this script:

```
INSERT INTO public.user (id, first_name, last_name, username, "password")
VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe', 'johndoe', '...');
INSERT INTO public.user (id, first_name, last_name, username, "password")
VALUES (2, 'Frank', 'James', 'frank', '...');
INSERT INTO public.user (id, first_name, last_name, username, "password")
VALUES (3, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'foo', '...');

ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_user RESTART;
UPDATE public.user SET id = DEFAULT;
```

However, when I run my app and try to add new user, this user id takes 0 and then 1 that throws error. So, how can I make this sequence start to give numbers from 4 ?

**Update:** Create Table statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS public.sequence_user START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 5;


CREATE TABLE public."user"
(
    id         BIGINT       NOT NULL,
    first_name VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    last_name  VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    username   VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    password   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_user PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: You need to link column to sequence, for example using OWNED BY

Comment: `ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_user RESTART WITH 4;` --> not working

Comment: `SELECT setval(''sequence_user'', max(id)) FROM public.user;` --> ERROR: syntax error at or near "sequence_user"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move the sequence to an arbitrary position, you can use [`setval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html):

```sql
select setval('public.sequence_user',
              (select max(id) from public.user) );
```

Note that [`INCREMENT BY 5`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) means the sequence will always move forward in steps of 5. You could also properly link the sequence to the column:

```sql
alter sequence public.sequence_user owned by public.user.id;
alter table public.user 
   alter column id 
   set default nextval('public.sequence_user');
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.user','id'),
              (select max(id) from public.user) );
```

It's best to let the db create, handle and maintain your `id` sequence:

```sql
create table public.user (
   id int generated by default as identity primary key, 
   first_name text, 
   last_name  text, 
   username   text, 
   "password" text);

select pg_get_serial_sequence('public.user','id');--public.user_id_seq
```

In both cases the sequence becomes the generator of default values but still lets you insert rows of your own, as long as you let it know afterwards: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/hY0OS5hm)

```sql
insert into public.user (id, first_name, last_name, username, "password")
values 
  (1, 'John', 'Doe', 'johndoe', '...')
, (2, 'Frank', 'James', 'frank', '...')
, (3, 'Foo', 'Bar', 'foo', '...');

select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.user','id'),
              (select max(id) from public.user) );

insert into public.user (id, first_name, last_name, username, "password")
values (default, 'Adam', 'Savage', 'adamsavage', '...');

insert into public.user (first_name, last_name, username, "password")
values ('Adam', 'Sandler', 'adamsandler', '...');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. `SELECT setval('sequence_user', max(id)) FROM public.user;` also solved the problem.